# Libre and open office not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org

I was trying to install open office using the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/office 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openoffice
```

But I am getting error in the second step.

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-0/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-0/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/office/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/office/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Can someone please help me in this.

Comment: LibreOffice isn't the same as OpenOffice. Most Linux distros offer LibreOffice. Have you tried `ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4`? See https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/libreoffice-4-4 for details.

Comment: Worth a look: https://blogs.gnome.org/uraeus/2015/08/17/an-open-letter-to-apache-foundation-and-apache-openoffice-team/

Comment: That's your PPA? ppa:upubuntu-com/office

Answer (score 1):

This PPA offers no packages for your version (14.04) of Ubuntu. In one glance: on this page https://launchpad.net/~upubuntu-com/+archive/ubuntu/office there are no packages for "Trusty", which is what the installer looks for. Only much older versions are supported by this PPA.

As @DKBose mentions, simply install LibreOffice (if it isn't installed yet).